# Parent-Child Relationship: E-R Diagram

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Would you please let me know a reference document or web references for a good E-R diagram displaying Parent Child relationships between the tables (Min. of 8 tables) with MS SQL Server 2008 database?

I am planning to design a big database, so looking forward for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Oracle's Datamodeler Tool](http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/database/datamodeler/index.html).